# Unable to display capital letter file name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have uploaded multiple files in CodeIgniter and it was working fine in localhost but when I upload it live server then those image doesn't display that name is in capital letter. I successfully store lower case file in a database but in the folder(where file store) I couldn't change the file name in lower case(i think that is the problem).
here is my controller

```
public function create() {
    // Check login
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('users/login');
    }

    $data['title']= $title = 'Create List';
    $path = 'assets/images/posts/';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $files = $_FILES;
        $image = $files['images']['name'][0]; 
        $img = strtolower($image);
        $totimg = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

        if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0])) {
            $post_image = $_FILES['images'];

            if ($this->upload_files($path, $title, $post_image) === FALSE) {
$data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('file_size_exceeded', 'Your uploaded file size is too large');
                $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
                redirect('posts');             
            }



        if (!isset($data['error'])) {
            $this->post_model->create_post($files,$totimg);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
            redirect('posts');
        } 
        }
    }
}

 private function upload_files($path, $title, $files)
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => $path,
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
        'overwrite'     => 1,
        'max_size'      => 2000,
        'remove_spaces' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {

        $_FILES['images[]']['name']= $files['name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['type']= $files['type'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $files['tmp_name'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['error']= $files['error'][$key];
        $_FILES['images[]']['size']= $files['size'][$key];

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('images[]')) {
            $this->upload->data();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

My model is following

```
public function create_post($post_image,$totimg){
                    $this->load->helper('inflector');
                    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
                    $image = implode(',',$post_image['images']['name']);
                    $file_name = underscore(strtolower($image));
                    $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'post_image' => $file_name
        );
                    return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Change filenames to the exact case that is in the db and that should settle it

Comment: `Linux` is case-sensitive, `filename` is not equal to `FILENAME`

Comment: have you tried this?
$new_name = time().$_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
$config['file_name'] = $new_name;

Comment: @Mr.Blue I got your reply but one issue will be there if upload same name file then in folder file change as filename(1) but in display, it will show the previous file like filename.. how can i come out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, `create()` function - did `strtolower()` and `underscore()` to target filenames so that saved filename and database filename are the same. To avoid same filename copy issue (where ci adds copy number in duplicate filenames
 - file1.jpg, file2.jpg ..), added time() to target filenames to make them unique.

**Right after:**

```
$files = $_FILES;
```

**Add:**

```
$this->load->helper('inflector');
for($i = 0;$i <count($files['images']['name']); $i++){
        $files['images']['name'][$i] = time()."_".underscore(strtolower($files['images']['name'][$i]));
}
```

**Replace:**

```
$post_image = $_FILES['images'];
```

**With:**

```
$post_image = $files['images'];
```

**Create()** function

**Updated Code:**

```
public function create() {
    // Check login
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('users/login');
    }

    $data['title']= $title = 'Create List';
    $path = 'assets/images/posts/';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $files = $_FILES;

        $this->load->helper('inflector');
        for($i = 0;$i <count($files['images']['name']); $i++){
            $files['images']['name'][$i] = time()."_".underscore(strtolower($files['images']['name'][$i]));
        }

        $image = $files['images']['name'][0]; 
        $img = strtolower($image);
        $totimg = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

        if (!empty($_FILES['images']['name'][0])) {
            $post_image = $files['images'];

            if ($this->upload_files($path, $title, $post_image) === FALSE) {
$data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata('file_size_exceeded', 'Your uploaded file size is too large');
                $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
                redirect('posts');             
            }



        if (!isset($data['error'])) {
            $this->post_model->create_post($files,$totimg);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
            redirect('posts');
        } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.. Now i'll add time at the beginning of file name.. so it'll be unique name

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I have done the same thing earlier but you help me a lot.
Thanks